# Accidently merged sent emails with inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I messed up my outlook account by setting up wrong mail transfer rules. Is there a way to determine sent emails from one account midst other mails in inbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way would be to search the mailbox for anything `From:` your email address that wasn't also sent `To:` your email address. (You skip such things as notes-to-self that way)

Comment: Hi @Mikey

This is what i have done, I guess i panicked too quickly, appreciate your response though!

Comment: Nothing worse than that heart attack "I just trashed my data" moment. Glad you got it working though!